# Adding Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2 to PCL is not working using Nuget

Tags: c#, json.net, nuget

I get the following error when I try to install package Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2 using Nuget:

Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+DNXcore50+win+wpa81', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

My solution contains a PCL, Shared Project, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 Project.

How can I add Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2?

Comment: What IDE are you using? The DNXCore50 framework is unknown in Visual Studio 2013 and Xamarin Studio so if that has been added to your PCL profile then it can cause the error you are seeing. Visual Studio 2015 is not affected by this.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013. Is there a way to safely delete the DNXCore50 from the PCL profile?

Comment: I believe the DNXCore50 PCL profile breaking Visual Studio 2013 is a [bug](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1562) with the first release of the Windows 10 SDK Tools. You can try updating that. Or you can rename the ASP.NET Core 5.0.xml files so the file extension is not .xml. The profile you have looks like profile 78 so you should be able to do this in just one directory - C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile78\SupportedFrameworks and then restart Visual Studio 2013.